# iTextSharp: Regenerate PDF file trailer

Tags: .net, pdf-generation, itext

In an XX scenario, we optimize and add textboxes and stuff in some source pdf file and then save it for our customers to be able to fill them in automatically from our asp.net website.

Lately I am facing a problem with the writing stuff which is as follows,

I am getting "trailer not found" io exception when trying to open and write the pdf file with itextsharp. After further investigation I realized that the PDF source file itself doesn't have any trailer near the end.

My question is, is there a way to regenerate the trailers? Or a free tool to repair pdf which re-creates the trailers? I tried few online tools but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it using pdftk. Unlike ghostscript it preservs the form fields and reconstructs the trailers nice and fine.

pdftk.exe coorruptedfile.pdf output fixedfile.pdf

worked like a charm

Comment: +1 Found this useful when I received a binary stream from a JSON that didn't have a trailer to the PDF and was using PDFSharp nuget.

Answer (score 1):

If your files can be opened by Acrobat Reader or Professional then you can these tools to correct your files.

Adobe tools reconstruct broken files and offer to resave them.

In addition, some PDF libraries can do the same.

Comment: Acrobat reader 9 doesn't have any repair option. I can fix the file using ghost script but problem is it wipes out all form fields. Ideas?

Comment: @user446923 Reader should ask whether you want to save file when you try to close window with a broken PDF. Do you see such prompts for your files? There is nore repair options other than that. I mean there is no repair menu or something.

Comment: Ah yeah I tried that + I also tried resaving the document using Save As as I read somewhere that Acrobat then consolidates lots of stuff and repairs meta and stuff. But I was with no luck. When I opened the file in Notepad++ it was still missing trailers. Ghost script was generating trailer but was wiping out form fields so finally I ended up using pdftk and it worked. Thanks for the tips though it helped me think hard.

Comment: @user446923 Are you sure that Acrobat saved your file without cross-reference streams (PDF 1.5 and later feature)? If file contains such streams then trailer info is placed into the stream dictionary part (there is info, but there is no classic trailer dictionary).